# Add component Input() with dot notation options: attr.src, style.padding.px

Tags: angular, typescript

I see a lot of Angular directives have dot notation options:

```
style.padding.px
style.padding.%
attr.src
```

And some libraries like [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) use it for different responsive sizes:

```
fxLayout.gt-sm
fxAlign.sm
```

Is it possible to do this with a component `@Input`?

If not, how are these other guys doing it? Or are they creating a new input for each possible name:

```
@Input('style.padding.px') paddingPx
@Input('style.padding.%') paddingPercent
...
```

**EDIT**

My use case:

I want to be able to 'catch all' or dynamically add more `@Input()`'s.

So say I have a `@Input('size')`  option.. I'd like to be able to add `size.sm`, `size.md` ect which in this case would be pulled from [flex-layouts custom breakpoints](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Breakpoints)

Answer (score 1):

The only option is to create an @Input() for each possible parameter

You can see how it is implemented in [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/blob/master/src/lib/flex/flex-align/flex-align.ts), for example